# Add Canvas and TextBlocks to giant Button in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, wpf-controls

I want to be able to add giant buttons to my ItemsControl. The giant button should contain a Canvas with multiple TextBlocks in it, like the Button in the following XAML code:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Click="add_Click">Add</Button>

    <ItemsControl Name="itemsControl">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <Button Width="450" Height="150" Margin="5" Name="button1" Background="DarkGreen">
            <Canvas>
                <TextBlock Canvas.Right="80" Canvas.Bottom="30" Background="RoyalBlue" Width="60" TextAlignment="Center" Name="person1">OR1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Canvas.Right="10" Canvas.Bottom="30" Background="SkyBlue" Width="60" TextAlignment="Center" Name="person2">Smith</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Canvas.Left="40" Canvas.Bottom="30" Background="Goldenrod" Width="60" TextAlignment="Center" Name="person3">CAM1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Canvas.Left="110" Canvas.Bottom="30" Background="HotPink" Width="60" TextAlignment="Center" Name="person4">Doe</TextBlock>
            </Canvas>
        </Button>
    </ItemsControl>
</DockPanel>
```

How can I add a giant button like the one in my XAML in my c# add_Click function? I have tried searching online, but haven't been able to find anything that achieves something similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options depending on what you want to do. If you only want to "add" a small number of buttons (2 - 3) you could change the visibility of each button in your add_Click method.

```
button1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

This is not the best option but it is technically easy.

The better approach would be to [build a user control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32825/How-to-Creating-a-WPF-User-Control-using-it-in-a-W) containing everything you want. Then create an observable collection of these buttons in your view model. Once this is done you can [bind the item control itemsource to your collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025958/how-to-dynamically-add-usercontrol-to-itemscontrol).

Finally, in your codebehind you can create collections of these buttons e.g.

```
GiantButtonCollection.Add(new GiantButton())
```

This is much better (but requires more work/knowledge)